# Obter JSON em Javascript (através de URI ou PHP)?

Tags: php, javascript, json, dropdownlist

Neste momento encontro-me a elaborar um projeto, sendo que, tenho necessidade de chamar um webservice que deverá retomar um json, para posteriormente o mesmo ser interpretado e poder preencher uma dropdown list. Na verdade, parte do código que eu necessito para este trabalho, já o encontrei, num artigo aqui na web, mas existe um problema. O JSON, está guardado numa variavel local,sendo que eu necessito de obter o mesmo de um webservice REST.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        var myjson;
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/revistaSystem/resplaneamento/ServicoComposicao/ObterTodasAsComposicoes/", function(json){
            myjson = json;
            console.log(json);
        });

        function PopulateDropDownList() {
           //Build an array containing Customer records.
            /*
            var customers = [
                { CustomerId: 1, Name: "John Hammond", Country: "United States" },
                { CustomerId: 2, Name: "Mudassar Khan", Country: "India" },
                { CustomerId: 3, Name: "Suzanne Mathews", Country: "France" },
                { CustomerId: 4, Name: "Robert Schidner", Country: "Russia" }
            ];*/

            var customers = myjson;

            var ddlCustomers = document.getElementById("ddlCustomers");

            //Add the Options to the DropDownList.
            for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement("OPTION");

                //Set Customer Name in Text part.
                option.innerHTML = customers[i].Name;

                //Set CustomerId in Value part.
                option.value = customers[i].CustomerId;

                //Add the Option element to DropDownList.
                ddlCustomers.options.add(option);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Eu preçiso de obter o json e processar o mesmo antes da página ser completamente carregada, portanto, optei por na página html:

```
<body onload="PopulateDropDownList()">
</body>
```

Como podem observar acima eu pretendo carregar o JSON,e fiz algumas tentativas que fracassaram. Como trabalho tambem com php, neste projeto então tentei tambem obter o JSON a partir do PHP, para posteriormente colocar-lo do lado do javascript. Tive bastantes dificuldades.

```
  <?php
    $uri ="http://localhost:8080/revistaSystem/resplaneamento/ServicoComposicao/ObterTodasAsComposicoes/";
    $json = file_get_contents($uri);
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    echo json_encode($obj);

  ?>
```

Resumo: Eu preçiso de obter o JSON,a partir de uma URI, e após obter este, preencher uma dropdown list, com valores. Todo este processo tem de ser realizado antes de carregar a página. Apenas por curiosidade, fazendo a chamada ao meu webservice REST, ele devolve o JSON no seguinte formato :

```
[{"numPK":1,"composicao":"100% Algodao"},{"numPK":2,"composicao":"40% Linho/60% Algodao"},{"numPK":3,"composicao":"30% Linho/70% Algodao"}]
```

Será que me podem facultar um exemplo concreto. Desde já Obrigado!

Comment: `$.getJSON` é assíncrono e não vai esperar capturar o resultado para depois exibir. O correto é você chamar a função `PopulateDropDownList` dentro do *callback* do `$.getJSON`, ao invés do `onload`. Se você precisa fazer essa requisição antes da página ser carregada, eu aconselho adicionar uma tela de *loading* ao invés de utilizar *requisições síncronas*.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode forçar ele esperar um processo terminar pra inicializar outro com 
 async: true ou false.

```
exemplo
 url: url,
 mtype: 'GET',
 datatype: 'json',
 async: false,
```